# In Canon EOS 1100D how do you manually set shutter speed and ISO in M mode?

Tags: canon, iso, shutter-speed, camera-controls

Can someone explain how to set the shutter speed and ISO in M(manual) mode in a canon EOS 1100D.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutter speed - "dial" button (cog wheel-check manual page 18 for position if not sure) just next to shutter(manual page 97)

ISO speed - press up arrow and navigate either with arrows to sides or with "dial" (manual page 77)

Comment: The full Instruction Manual is [available in PDF](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004730/01/eosrt3-eos1100d-im-en.pdf).

Answer (score -2):

I use 125 shutter speed when using the manual mode in daylight, if I am not happy with the results I keep trying till I find a shutter speed I am happy with. I tend to use F4 most of the time.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I think the user was more asking for instructions as to which buttons/dials to use to adjust the value, rather than deciding which value to pick.